# What is the equivalent of this python dictionary in Dart?

Tags: dart

What is the equivalent of this python dictionary in Dart?

```
edges = {(1, 'a') : 2,
         (2, 'a') : 2,
         (2, '1') : 3,
         (3, '1') : 3}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use `package:collection`'s [`EqualityMap`](https://www.dartdocs.org/documentation/collection/1.14.2/collection/EqualityMap-class.html) to define a custom hash algorithim that uses `ListEquality`. For example, you could do this:

```
var map = new EqualityMap.from(const ListEquality(), {
  [1, 'a']: 2,
  [2, 'a']: 2,
});

assert(map[[1, 'a']] == map[[1, 'a']])
```

This will be a heavier weight implementation of Map, though.

Comment: Everyone gave good points but your solution was the only one I could make it work completely in my program.

Answer (score 4):

You have differents way to do this

#### 1. Using a List

```
var edges = <List, num>{
  [1, 'a']: 2,
  [2, 'a']: 2,
  [2, '1']: 3,
  [3, '1']: 3
};
```

Simple to write, but you won't be able to retrieve data with

```
edges[[2, 'a']]; // null
```

Except if you use const

```
var edges = const <List, num>{
  const [1, 'a']: 2,
  const [2, 'a']: 2,
  const [2, '1']: 3,
  const [3, '1']: 3
};  

edges[const [2, 'a']]; // 2
```

#### 2. Using Tuple package

https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/tuple

```
var edges = <Tuple2<num, String>, num>{
  new Tuple2(1, 'a'): 2,
  new Tuple2(2, 'a'): 2,
  new Tuple2(2, '1'): 3,
  new Tuple2(3, '1'): 3
}

edges[new Tuple2(2, 'a')]; // 2
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Could you explain why you are able to retrieve the data when you use const?

Comment: hum, actually that is a good question, you could find an answer on gitter by directly asking to the Dart team or people with more experience than me https://gitter.im/dart-lang/TALK-general

Comment: because `[1, 'a']` does not "==" `[1, 'a']` - they are different objects, but const makes them the same object.

Answer (score 0):

```
  var edges = {[1, 'a'] : 2,
               [2, 'a'] : 2,
               [2, '1'] : 3,
               [3, '1'] : 3};
```

Except that you won't ever be able to look up those keys, because a new instance of `[1, 'a']` will be a different object.